# Invalid Values error when attempting to use 'append' in google sheets API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to append information onto a spreadsheet with the following code.

```
    let values = [
        [
            [tweet.user.name, tweet.user.client_id]
        ]
    ];

    let resource = {
        values,
    };

    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', oAuth2Client});

    sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: oAuth2Client,
    spreadsheetId: '***redacted***',
    range: 'A:C',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    resource,
}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
    // Handle error.
    console.log(err);
    } else {
    console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
    }
});
```

However I am receiving this error. I think it's some sort of formatting issue, but I have no idea what it could be.

'Invalid values[2][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "Structure of Reign"\n  }\n  values {\n    null_value: NULL_VALUE\n  }\n}\n',

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 4):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `values` is required to be 2 dimensional array.
- Result can be retrieved by `result.data`.
- `{\n values {\n string_value: "Structure of Reign"\n }\n values {\n null_value: NULL_VALUE\n }\n}\n` indicates that `tweet.user.client_id` is undefined, while `tweet.user.name` has a value of `Structure of Reign`.

  - About this, please confirm `tweet.user.client_id`, because I'm not sure about your situation.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
let values = [[[tweet.user.name, tweet.user.client_id]]];
```

To:

```
let values = [[tweet.user.name, tweet.user.client_id]];
```

And

From:

```
console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
```

To:

```
console.log(`${result.data.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that you can use Sheets API.
- When other error occurs even if you modified those, please confirm the following points.

  1. Update "googleapis" to the latest version.
  2. Whether Sheets API is enabled at API console.
  3. Whether the access token has the scopes for using the method of values.append.

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

If this modification didn't work, I apologize.